# Web API OData ignore properties added by client-side

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I get an error when I call Put to my server using WebApi Odata v4.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "job : The property 'test' does not exist on type 'Model.Temp'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.\r\n",
            "type": "",
            "stacktrace": ""
        }
    }
}
```

this error happens because the property "test" is not set in the Model "Temp". it is actually added by javascript, and only used in client-side

How do I make so that OData will just ignore properties that are not available in the Model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to deal with your scenario. It is not to ignore the properties, but to accept them by defining the entity type as an open type so that it can accept dynamic properties which are not defined in the model from the client and store them for future queries if necessary.

You can find the following tutorial for implementing an open type support: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

Comment: Thanks. Although this means I need to add one more property, I can accept this solution for now.

Perhaps it might be better if there is a way to do it as a config

Comment: @Habibi & Yi Ding, I don't think "opening an entity" is the right choice here. You simply should not send values and expect the server to ignore them. Open entity should persist the dynamic properties, not ignore them. In my humble opinion I think though the proposed solution will work, it's a bad design for a service.